# SAS PROC SQL join and replace

Tags: sql, sas

I have two datasets that I want to join.  The small dataset is my base dataset and has data like the following (Call it DSsmall):

```
ID   NAME   COV_DATE  PRODUCT
1   A_PART   1/1/2014    BOX
1   A_PART   2/1/2014    BOX
2   A_PART   1/1/2014    BOX
3   B_PART   1/1/2014    BOX
```

The larger dataset has duplicates in it so it might look like this (Call it DSLarge):

```
ID  END_DATE PERSON_NAME
1    1/1/2012    MAX
1    1/1/2015    MAX
2    2/1/2012    SALLY
2    5/1/2014    SALLY
3    1/1/2014    JOE
```

IDS 1 & 2 of are actually the same -- they have the same name, they should both be under the same ID, not two different IDs  I've joined the datasets using the latest END_DATE from DSLarge.  That works.  But now I want to combine the two ids based on the higher number.  So for IDs 1 & 2 I want all recs with ID 1 to be ID 2 -- can I do this in SQL?

Comment: You mean **rows** 1 and 2 are the same (ID=1)?  ID1 and ID2 have different names, Max and Sally.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the result that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean **rows** 1 and 2 are the same, you can group by easily here.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as 
    select id, person_name, max(end_date)
    from dsLarge
    group by id, person_name;
quit;
```

If they could have different person names and you still want to collapse them, you would want to somehow clarify the person name issue - such as `max(person_name)` or similar.

Data step will do this more efficiently (or at least the same and possibly more efficiently), by the way, but the SQL method is perfectly fine if your needs are simple like this.

Comment: I tried to edit my question for clarity but it never saved so I'll try to explain.  I want to JOIN the two datasets so that eventually I will get this:
ID   NAME   COV_DATE  PRODUCT  END_DATE   PERSON_NAME
2   A_PART   1/1/2015    BOX              1/1/2015         Max
3   B_PART   1/1/2014    BOX              1/1/2014         JOE

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that want rows 1 and 2 in DSSmall to have an `ID` of 2 because they share a `NAME` with row 3 then you can do this like so:

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select
        max(ID) as ID,
        NAME,
        COV_DATE,
        PRODUCT
    from DSsmall
    group by NAME;
quit;
```